# IOS : LinkedIn Sign In is not redirecting to webpage when app is not installed

Tags: ios, objective-c, linkedin-api

I am trying to integrate the linkedin in my ios application.I have observed that if the app is not installed my app shows to install the linkedin application instead of redirecting to web browser like facebook and gmail does.I would like to know weather linkedin supports this kind of things i.e redirecting to webpage if application is not installed or i have to write the custom code for that If so please help me with the custom code to be written when linkedin app is not installed and also when installed.
I have written the code as below after integrating the linkedin sdk in my application.

```
 LISDKSessionManager createSessionWithAuth:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:LISDK_BASIC_PROFILE_PERMISSION, LISDK_EMAILADDRESS_PERMISSION, nil]
 state:nil
 showGoToAppStoreDialog:YES
 successBlock:^(NSString *returnState) {
     NSLog(@"%s","success called!");
     LISDKSession *session = [[LISDKSessionManager sharedInstance] session];
     NSLog(@"value=%@ isvalid=%@",[session value],[session isValid] ? @"YES" : @"NO");
     NSMutableString *text = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:[session.accessToken description]];
     [text appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@",state=\"%@\"",returnState]];
     NSLog(@"Response label text %@",text);
 }
 errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
     NSLog(@"%s","error called!");
 }
 ];
```

Comment: I read linkedin iOS SDK docs but there isn't any clear info.I suggest try setting "showGoToAppStoreDialog" to NO if by chance it takes you to webpage as gmail or fb do.

Comment: if you want to integrate linkdin sdk it is  needed to have a LinkDin app in your device if not it will automatically redirects to store to install app , all of this only happens in real device no simulator

Comment: You can check this out http://www.appcoda.com/linkedin-sign-in/ but it uses OAuth 2.0.

Comment: Thanks for the info appcoda shows the code written in swift .But i needed that in objective c and also provide the sample code for this if possible

Answer (score 0):

If the app is not installed on your device it will call error block and you have to show an alert to user that you have to download app from app store. User can click NO and then it will go with OAuth login.

```
-(void)loginViaLinkedIn
 {
  __weak __typeof(self)weakSelf = self;
[LISDKSessionManager createSessionWithAuth:[NSArray 
arrayWithObjects:LISDK_BASIC_PROFILE_PERMISSION, nil]
                                     state:@"some state"
                    showGoToAppStoreDialog:YES
                              successBlock:^(NSString *returnState) {

                                  NSLog(@"%s","success called!");
                                  LISDKSession *session = [[LISDKSessionManager sharedInstance] session];
                                  NSLog(@"value=%@ isvalid=%@",[session value],[session isValid] ? @"YES" : @"NO");
                                  [weakSelf getLinkedInDetail];
                              }
                                errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                                    NSDictionary * userInfoDic = [error userInfo];
                                    NSString * info = [[userInfoDic allKeys] firstObject];
                                    if([info isEqualToString:@"You need to download the LinkedIn App in order to connect with LinkedIn"] && error.code == 3)
                                    {
                                        [weakSelf loginViaOAuthProtocol];
                                        // Linkedin native app not available , login with OAuth
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        [weakSelf linkedinAuthenticationResponse:nil error:error];
                                    }
                                }
 ];

 }
```

Comment: As i am new to developing can u provide me code for  method loginViaOAuthProtocol if so it will be great helpful to me

Comment: How can I login via OAuth protocol? I can´t find it in official docs

Answer (score -1):

You can read the official documentation about it. 
"Understanding the mobile authentication user experience" 
There are several possible scenarios that could occur which result in different user experiences, based on:

```
-Is the LinkedIn application installed on the device?
-Is the user a LinkedIn member?
-Is the user signed into the LinkedIn application on their device?
-Has the user granted your application permission to access their profile?
```

All of this is explained in:
https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/ios-sdk-auth#ux